# Sliders episode identification (Season 4?)

Tags: story-identification, episode-identification, sliders

I have very little on the episode itself, but I believe it may be from Season 4. All I remember is that Quinn and Rembrandt are discussing their sliding adventures with a woman from that world, and how, on occasion, certain tools or materials are needed to help them on their journey.

Quinn states that these materials were acquired, and Rembrandt says something like, "Yeah, more like stolen."

Quinn, looking out a window when Rembrandt says this, turns and winks at him.

Comment: Didn't Quinn leave the show before season 4?

Comment: @Paul - no, he left during the fifth season, early on if I remember rightly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's Season 4, Episode 2, "Prophets and Loss".

You have the scene nearly correct, but the context is a little different.

Rembrandt, Maggie and Quinn are discussing the apparent sliding technology the Oracle religion has. Quinn wants to get a look at it. The discussion happens at roughly the 10:55 mark into the episode. Quinn is looking out a window, exactly as you describe.

> Quinn: I gotta get a look at the mechanics of that machine. I'm
> getting nowhere adjusting the timer. If they have sliding technology,
> they might have something I can borrow or copy.
>
> Rembrandt: Or steal.

He then winks at Rembrandt also exactly as you describe, so I'm quite certain this is the scene in question:

[image: Winky winky]

Answer (score 0):

Since I first read this question, I've rewatched the entire run of Sliders.  While I can't promise my full attention was on it at all times (the show got very, very bad on occasion), I was specifically looking for the scene you describe (but don't blame yourself, I was planning on rewatching the series anyway).

And, to the best of my knowledge and observation, that scene does not exist in any episode.  There is a slim chance it occurred during a moment that my mind wandered drastically out of a desire to protect me from stupid, but I don't believe so, and I paid particular attention whenever they either told someone about their adventures, or needed to steal something.  Unfortunately, as transcripts of all the episodes do not seem to exist on the net, it is hard to verify with simple searches, but I'm confident enough to give it as an answer.

I think it's more likely that you are either confusing it with a different show, or misremembering a part of a piece of tie-in media like a comic or particularly well-done fanfic with a scene like this and your imagination filled in enough details to give you a memory of it happening in video form.

Comment: No, the woman is Maggie. I don't recall the episode, but I saw the scene some time after posting the question.

Comment: @T-1000'sSon: Shame you didn't come back to write an answer!

Comment: Anyway, if it was Maggie, and she was "from that world", then presumably this was _The Exodus_?